# XML marshalling in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a JdbcCursorItemReader which reads from a database and uses a row mapper to turn the resultset into an object. The requirement is now to marshall the object into XML, which must then be placed onto a message queue.

Three questions:

**1.** Should a marshaller in Spring Batch be implemented as an ItemProcessor or as an ItemWriter?

**2.** There is no need to write the XML to a file, but rather simply send it as a string object in a message. What is the best way in Spring Batch to do this?

**3.** If the marshaller and message dispatcher should both be implemented as separate writers, how is it possible to chain them.

Any example code or links would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom writer which will be used when data is written via ItemWriter.

A sample code [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-mysql-database-to-xml/) with some modifications as per your requirement:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

public class CustomXMLWriter extends org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter<User> {

    private Writer myWriter;

    /**
     * Subclasses can override to customize the writer.
     */
    @Override
    protected XMLEventWriter createXmlEventWriter(XMLOutputFactory outputFactory, Writer writer)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        myWriter = new StringWriter();
        return outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(myWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        String outputXML = myWriter.toString() + "</" + this.getRootTagName() + ">";
        System.out.println(outputXML);
        // code here to add the resultant XML string in message queue
        super.close();
    }

}
```

In this example you have to mention output resource but the resultant XML file always contains just root tag name.

**XML:**

```
<bean id="customXMLItemWriter" class="com.mkyong.CustomXMLWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/users.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="userUnmarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="users" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. One thing, looks like this code needs to be added to the close() method: myWriter.append("</"+this.getRootTagName()+">"); Otherwise, the xml will not be closed with the root tag.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please let me whether it is working or not as per your requirement.

Comment: looks good so far, thanks. Am going to try to put this ItemWriter in one step, and then have a second step which picks up the output of the first step. The second step would use a JMSItemWriter.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer to append root tag name also in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought Spring Batch could use a `ChannelItemWriter` for a while now.  If you approached this from the perspective that you write the XML snips to a Spring Integration Channel (that can be then backed by a message queue), you could write the custom `ItemWriter` that way.  That would allow you to approach the item conversion a couple different ways (either in the `ItemProcessor` or in via a transformer in Spring Integration).  If you pursue this approach, I'd recommend contributing the writer back to Spring Batch.

Comment: Do not understand what you mean. How would you get the XML marshalling done via an ItemProcessor in Spring Batch ?

Comment: You'd have to implement a custom `ItemProcessor` that took in your item and returned a String and did the marshaling manually.  There is no component within Spring Batch to do this out of the box.